# Possible to Host Firestore Onsite?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore for a project in a developing country with intermittent internet access. The internet may go down for up to a day. The client has other systems that use an onsite instance (ie a server they have that runs SQLServer) - that way the systems are still operational if the internet access goes down.

Is it possible to set up Firestore similarly - so that apps that use Firestore can still access it without internet access? If not, what could be a recommended workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Cloud Firestore is only available as a cloud-hosted database.  There are no "on prem" solutions to run it outside of Google's cloud.

Firebase provides a local emulator, but that's only suitable for running local tests.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDvdAFP6OhQ

Firestore is not designed to work as a standalone database. However, it's designed to withstand longer periods of downtime, hours and even days. But if it's days - you should already consider a different solution.

In your case, I suspect what you'd like to have various clients synchronized even if the Internet is down. This will not work in Firestore as each client would have its own copy of the cache. Thus I wouldn't recommend using Firestore in your scenario.